# Caractere Especial com Scanner e FileReader

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um arquivo.txt com os seguintes valores:

```
TESTE
17,00%
01/01/2014
25,55
AÇAILANDIA
```

Ao importar esse txt na minha aplicação Java o caractere especial Ç não é importado ficando o resultado assim:

```
TESTE
17,00%
01/01/2014
25,55
A�AILANDIA
```

Abaixo o método que utilizo para importar o arquivo:

```
private void lerArquivo4() throws FileNotFoundException {
        //https://blog.caelum.com.br/lendo-arquivos-texto-em-java/
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/jallisson/Desktop/testejj.txt")).useDelimiter("\\||\\n");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String numero = scanner.next();
            String matricula = scanner.next();
            String materia = scanner.next();
            String prova = scanner.next();
            String nota = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(numero);
            System.out.println(matricula);
            System.out.println(materia);
            System.out.println(prova);
            System.out.println(nota);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, nota, "Linha", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no momento da leitura do arquivo.

Como você está utilizando apenas o [FileReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), será assumido o charset default (no caso da sua JVM deve ser `ISO-8859-1`, pode ser facillmente checado através de `Charset.defaultCharset()`)

Citando o trecho da documentação:

> The constructors of this class assume that the **default character encoding** and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate.

Podemos então ler o arquivo definindo o charset para `UTF-8`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream("C:/Users/jallisson/Desktop/testejj.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
            .useDelimiter("\\||\\n");
```

O resultado de saída será como o esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: valeu amigo deu certo, somente modifiquei o "UFT-8" por "ISO-8859-1"